# Finding Max and Min Temp from Max TemperatureC and TemperatureC with Date

Tags: python-3.x

I have csv files, I want to find the Max and Min Temperature from Max TemperatureC and Min TemperatureC, and print output with its corresponding **date** as mentioned in the row, using only simple csv module.

This problem can be solved by pandas module but I want code only using with simple csv module.

thank you
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXgzy.png)